# Как с помощью os.walk задать поиск по всему ПК?

Tags: python, поиск

`os.walk()`

Как задать поиск по всему компьютеру?

Comment: Во-первых, какая ОС? Во-вторых, что входит в понятие «весь пк»? Системные разделы? Виртуальные файловые системы? Служебные объекты ядра NT (которые иногда доступны в виде файлов)?

Comment: Вообще интересно для windiws и Линукс ..весь пк имеется ввиду все возможные директории которые есть на ПК.

Comment: Нужно ли учитывать непримонтированные файловые системы? Если на ПК примонтирована удалённая файловая система (NFS, SMB, WebDAV и т. п.) — нужно ли их учитывать или пропустить?

Comment: Если не возможно зайти в директорию сообщает сообщение об этом.

Comment: `os.walk('/')` ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor если правильно помню, в винде это пройдёт только по текущему диску

Comment: @andreymal Я имел в виду линукс.

Comment: Да в Винде это только потекущуму каталогу os.walk('/') и то лучше указать os.walk('//')

Answer (score 2):

```
from ctypes import windll
def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
             drives.append(letter+':\\')
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives
for d in get_drives():
    os.walk(d) # windows
```

---

```
os.walk('/') # linux
```

Answer (score -1):

Я не очень опытен в этом вопросе,но если вам нужен поиск по нескольким дискам,то попробуйте это:

os.walk ('C:\\ ')

os.walk ('D:\\ ')

и просто прописывайте эту команду дальше,лишь заменяя букву диска на нужную вам,
вдруг сработает

Comment: Это все понятно, хочется чтобы это все автоматические происходидило и не чего дописывать не нужно.